# projective non-singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am working on algebraic curves at the moment and I can not find a proper definition of the projective non-singular curves. My goal is understand that the category of non-singular projective curves is equivalent to the finite generated field extension of k of transendence degree 1.
Now an abstract non singular curves is just a open subset over $C_k$ where this is just the set of all dvr.

But what is a projective non-singular curve.
I am glad for any hints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **variety**: integral scheme of finite type over a field. (This may vary *a lot* in literature: one can add "separated", remove "integral", add "reduced" again...).
2. **curve**: one-dimensional variety.
3. **projective** (over a field): closed subvariety of some projective space (over that field).
4. **nonsingular**: all local rings at closed points are regular local rings.

Hence a projective nonsingular curve is a one-dimensional projective variety all of whose local rings (at closed points) are discrete valuation rings (as DVR means: regular local ring of dimension one).

The equivalence of categories you are working with is provided by the *function field* functor:
$$C\mapsto K(C)=\{\textrm{rational functions on }C\}.$$
It is important to note that for $K(-)$ to be an equivalence, one has to consider the category of curves with arrows the *dominant* morphisms of curves. In addition, a third category is equivalent to the tho above: that of *curves, with dominant rational maps*.

Comment: Also note that for curves, regular is equivalent to normal.